# Loading message with Pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

I want to print a nice loading message with these three fading dots, while the main thread does some heavy IO stuff. This is why I implemented this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static bool            loadingStop;
static pthread_mutex_t loadingMutex;

void *loadingDots(void *message);

int main() {
  loadingStop = false;

  // MUTEX
  pthread_mutex_init(&loadingMutex, NULL);

  // ATTRIBUTE
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

  // THREAD
  pthread_t loadingThread;
  pthread_create(&loadingThread, &attr, loadingDots, (void *)"Loading (main, does something long)");

  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

  // SOMETHING TIME CONSUMING 
  usleep(8000000);

  // PLEASE 'LoadingDots' TO STOP
  pthread_mutex_lock(&loadingMutex);
  loadingStop = true;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&loadingMutex);

  // WAIT FOR IT TO FINISH
  pthread_join(loadingThread, NULL);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&loadingMutex);

  printf("This is printed after 'LoadingDots' savely quit.\n");

  return 0;
}

void *loadingDots(void *message)
{
  int c = 0;

  while (1) {
    switch (c) {
    case 0:
      printf("\r%s   \r%s", (char *)message, (char*)message);
      break;
    default:
      putchar('.');
      break;
    }

    fflush(stdout);
    usleep(1000000);

    c = (c+1) % 4;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&loadingMutex);
    if (loadingStop) { break; };
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&loadingMutex);
  }

  putchar('\n');
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly minor stuff

1. Good use of `fflush(stdout);` to insure output.  Something often missed.
2. Minor: `int main() {` is not explicitly allowed per the standard.  Better to use `int main(void) {`
3. Minor: Naked physical quantity.  Values like height, weight, time, should have units made clear  [feet vs meter $327.6 million mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter#Cause_of_failure)

   ```
   // usleep(8000000);
   #define SOME_us_TIME_CONSUMPTION (8000000 /* us */)
   usleep(SOME_us_TIME_CONSUMPTION);
   ```
4. Minor: Avoid `printf()` when `fputs()` will do.  Avoid `%` issue.. BTW did you mean "safely" vs "savely"?

   ```
   // printf("This is printed after 'LoadingDots' savely quit.\n");
   fputs("This is printed after 'LoadingDots' savely quit.\n", stdout);
   // or 
   puts("This is printed after 'LoadingDots' savely quit.");
   ```
5. Long lines: Respect the width for the target audience - in this case code review.

   ```
   // pthread_create(&loadingThread, &attr, loadingDots, (void *)"Loading (main, does something long)");
   ```
6. vs.

   ```
   pthread_create(&loadingThread, &attr, loadingDots, 
       (void *)"Loading (main, does something long)");
   ```
7. Consider auto format.  The space between `bool            loadingStop` will likely shrink with auto formatting.  Insure code is presentable even after auto formatting.

   ```
   // looks OK
   static bool loadingStop;
   static pthread_mutex_t loadingMutex;
   ```
8. Minor: Not a fan of `{}` one liners

   ```
   // if (loadingStop) { break; };
   if (loadingStop) { 
     break;
   };
   ```